# Alternative for qt 3d and opengl in qt

Tags: c++, qt, 3d

## My situation

I want to build a cross platform application, with a gui, that displays a 3d view of some simple cubes, that the user can interact with. Qt seemed like a good tool for the job and I think I have the gui part sufficiently down for the most part. For the 3d part OpenGl or the qt/3d implementation seemed like the right tool, but it does not work. When I try to run the examples from Qt, that use a 3d view, they are unstable, they crash, show a black window and on the offchance, that I find one, that does work there is aggressive flickering and my entire system becomes unresponsive when I only try to resize it. I don't know what is wrong, I don't think I can do a better job, than the official examples and I don't think, that trying to debug the examples is the way to go. (If someone has an idea how to fix this tell me, but I don't even have an error message)

## My question:

Is there a simple framework, that would allow me to display simple 3d shapes and include that in a Qt application. I don't need shadows, or reflections or transparency or anything more fancy, than ambient light. Just some solid coloured boxes I can rotate and click on. I think it would even be fine, if it ran on CPU rather than GPU. It would be nice, if I could keep using C++, but if it only exists in another language, what gives. I don't really want to build a framework from scratch. How could I include such a foreign framework in Qt?
I am using ubuntu 20.04 with intel graphics, but as I said, I want the resulting application to work on as many platforms as possible.

Comment: You might have to code a software renderer that works with qt widgets. There might be something like that on github.

Comment: ok, thank you. You mean I should look for a '3d software renderer for qt widgets' or something of that kind?

Comment: Typing "software renderer qt" is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an application that uses Qt3D with then OpenGL renderer. Deploying the app to a handful of users, I found some severe issues with Intel Integrated Graphics, ranging from crash to rendering bugs like flickering. This unfortunately doesn't comes from Qt or OpenGL itself but more from how Intel implements their OpenGL drivers.

The crash bug seems to impact older intel chips, very few references of that apart some random minecraft FAQ on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/48ktct/19_faqs/
But what is claimed there seem to align with what my users are experiencing.

The flickering bug has only been reported recently and I unfortunately don't have the right hardware to replicate it yet...

I know it's like random, not sourced information but I thought that personnal experience might help.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I will find access to other hardware, thank you for sharing your experience. If nothing else it gives me confidence, that it is not my fault or shortcoming. Wish you success with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I used osgQt many years ago. It looks active still. I know the military likes them.

https://github.com/openscenegraph/osgQt

Comment: @bananabook armed forces.... :(

Comment: I understand the word military, I was just confused what the military would do with a 3d renderer like this.

Comment: My first professional job after school was in a project for the dept of defense, building a multi monitor panel with distributed rendering to be used in the command center of a carrier. Viz is essential for the generals to understand the situation in real-time